# Is this a workable VLAN configuration?

Tags: vlan

I have three network switches wired and configured like this:

```
192.168.1.12
VLAN1:
    PORT 1 
    PORT 2 (U)
    PORT 3 (U)
    PORT 4 (U)
    PORT 5 
    PORT 6 
    PORT 7 
    PORT 8 (T)
VLAN3: 
    PORT 1
    PORT 2
    PORT 3
    PORT 4 
    PORT 5 
    PORT 6 
    PORT 7 (U)
    PORT 8 (T)

PORT 1 No connection
PORT 2 PC
PORT 3 PC
PORT 4 PC
PORT 5 No connection
PORT 6 No connection
PORT 7 No connection
PORT 8 Trunk link to 192.168.1.15 port 3
------------------------------------------
192.168.1.15
VLAN1:
    PORT 1 
    PORT 2 
    PORT 3 (T)
    PORT 4 (T)
    PORT 5 (U)
    PORT 6 
    PORT 7
    PORT 8
VLAN3: 
    PORT 1 
    PORT 2 
    PORT 3 (T)
    PORT 4 (T)
    PORT 5
    PORT 6 
    PORT 7
    PORT 8

PORT 1 RJ45 Socket
PORT 2 RJ45 Socket
PORT 3 Trunk link from 192.168.1.12 port 8
PORT 4 Trunk link from 192.168.1.14 port 5
PORT 5 NVR
PORT 6 No connection
PORT 7 No connection
PORT 8 No connection
------------------------------------------
192.168.1.14
VLAN1:
    PORT 1 (U)
    PORT 2 (U)
    PORT 3 (U)
    PORT 4 (U)
    PORT 5 (T)
VLAN3:
    PORT 1 (U)
    PORT 2 
    PORT 3 
    PORT 4 
    PORT 5 (T)

PORT 1 Router 192.168.1.254
PORT 2 TV
PORT 3 DVD
PORT 4 NAS
PORT 5 Trunk link to 192.168.1.15 port 4
```

The idea is that there are two separate VLANS - 1 & 3.  The only thing is that they both have access to the router on port 1 on 192.168.1.14

If I plugged a device in to port 7 on 192.168.1.12 (VLAN3), would I be able to ping the router?  I would have expected the route to go port 7 -> port 8 on 192.168.1.12 follow the trunk route port 3 -> port 3 on 192.168.1.15 follow the trunk route port 5 -> port 1 on 192.168.1.14

Since both VLANS 'share' the router, are VLANS1 & 3 connected in anyway or is their separation maintained because they are on different VLANS?

Thanks

Comment: With two VLANs, you need two router interfaces, one for each VLAN. You could use two physical interfaces, or two virtual interfaces on a single physical interface. Each VLAN will have a separate network, and hosts on each VLAN would use the router address for that VLAN as the gateway. VLANs are like separate, unconnected switches. The router can route between the VLANs, or you can use ACLs to restrict some or all the traffic between the VLANs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
192.168.1.14
VLAN1:
    PORT 1 (U)
    ...
VLAN3:
    PORT 1 (U)
    ...
PORT 1 Router 192.168.1.254
```

That won't work.

To trunk both VLANs to the router you'll need to tag at least one of them. One VLAN may remain untagged, but not both.

On the router, you need to configure each VLAN appropriately. Usually that is done directly on the physical interface for an untagged VLAN, and on a virtual subinterface for a tagged VLAN.

Also, you need to create an IP subnet for the additional VLAN (likely VLAN 3) and possibly a DHCP config.

As Ron's already commented, the router will route between the VLANs by default but you can set up an ACL to prevent that.